# How to include code in only one controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, conditional-statements

I have only a single page that requires jquery ui in my entire application. How can conditionally include the javascript files in that single page?

I believe in Rails 2 I could use: (in application.html.erb)

```
<%- if controller.controller_name == "posts" && controller.controller_action == "new" -%>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css' %> 
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js', 'autocomplete-rails.js' %>
<%- end -%>
```

But `controller.controller_action` throws an undefined method error. And after looking at the API, it looks like it's been removed?

Maybe it would be best to remove the conditional from `application.html.erb` altogether and just put it at the top of `posts/new.html.erb` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would avoid delegating responsibility for this to your application layout. If you don't need jQuery UI on more than a single view, you are best off letting the view handle that. The following let's you do just that while still keeping your output HTML clean and sensible (ie. not putting JS all over the place willy nilly).

In your layout (`application.html.erb`):

```
<head>
  <title>Foo Bar</title>
  <%= yield :page_specific_assets %>
</head>
```

In your view that requires jQuery UI (`posts/new.html.erb`):

```
<% content_for :page_specific_assets do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css' %> 
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js', 'autocomplete-rails.js' %>
<% end %>
```

Note: despite convention, putting unnecessary javascript in the `<head>` degrades performance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's:

```
controller.action_name
```